# How can I calculate mean of list of strings？

Tags: python-2.7, csv

I trying to calculate mean of one colum in a csv file.First, I read one column from `.csv` file and save it into a list. Next when I try to get mean it have a error

```
TypeError: 'builtin_function_or_method' object has no attribute '__getitem__'
```

my code is :

```
with open('XXXXXX.csv') as f:
reader = csv.DictReader(f) 
for row in reader: 
    for (k,v) in row.items(): 
        columns_95[k].append(v)
sVaR5 = columns_95['95%']
mean_95 = sum（sVaR5）/len(sVaR5)
```

and my csv looks like:

```
95%      99%
1.225    2.332
1.252    10.252
2.336    4.213
...      ...
```

when I check my list, output is`['1.225','1.252','2.336']` I think maybe the quote mark is the reason why my code has error. but how to fix it!Thanks!!!

Comment: Error is because of square brackets after `sum`: `sum[sVaR5]` should be `sum(sVaR5)`

Comment: And yes, the list contains strings, which you need to convert to numbers, e.g. with `sVaR5 = [float(x) for x in columns_95['95%']]`

Comment: Sorry my code is 'sum(sVaR5)' my mistake

Comment: and Thanks! your second comment it works! Thanks!

Comment: No problem. Those quotes just let you know that the list items are strings, as you'd expect from reading a text file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`sum`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#sum) is a function. If you want to call the function `sum` with the argument `sVaR5`, you need to write:

```
sum(sVaR5)
```

If your `sVaR5` is a list of strings, you could convert them to floats for the sum:

```
sum(map(float, sVaR5))
```

If you put `sum[sVaR5]`, Python tries to call `__getitem__` on the object `sum`, hence the error

```
'builtin_function_or_method' object has no attribute '__getitem__'
```